# How do I invoke Meteor.call multiple times in a loop in this context?

Tags: meteor

```
          for (var i = 0; i < reviewsObj.objects.length; i++){
            var reviewURL = reviewsObj.objects[i].url;

            // AT THIS POINT REVIEW URL VARIES

            Meteor.call("getURL", reviewURL, function(error, results){

                AT THIS POINT, REVIEW URL IS ONLY THE REVIEW URL VALUE OF THE LAST OBJECT IN THE ARRAY
                ... 
            });
          }
```

So my Meteor method getURL invokes a GET request using `Meteor.http.call`. However it seems that whenever `Meteor.call("getURL...` is invoked, the value of `reviewURL` is always the same (the last value in that loop).

Any input as to how I could go about working around this would be great.

Comment: I see this question getting downvotes, and would love an explanation to it?

Comment: @Louis93 probably because this is a well known jacascript gotcha that has been asked and answered may times before. Have a careful read of [JavaScript closures in for-loops](http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/62) for more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the modern version of that loop:

```
_.each(reviewsObj.objects, function(reviewObj) {
  Meteor.call('getURL', reviewObj.url, function(err, res) {
    ...
  });
});
```